# Can't use apt-get when docker-compose on a php container

Tags: php, docker, apt-get

I am trying to setup a container that is pulling `php:8.1-fpm` through docker-compose, but I need to a some libs from apt-get that I require `apt-get install -y php8.1-gmp`

**docker-compose**

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  php:
    image: php:8.1-fpm
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    command: bash -c "apt-get update && apt-get install -y php8.1-gmp"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html:rw,cached
  mysql:
    image: mysql:debian
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: database
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
  nginx:
    depends_on:
      - php
    image: nginx:1.19
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

but when I docker-compose I get an error

```bash
php_1    | Reading package lists...
php_1    | Reading package lists...
php_1    | Building dependency tree...
php_1    | Reading state information...
php_1    | E: Unable to locate package php8.1-gmp
php_1    | E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php8.1-gmp'
php_1    | E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php8.1-gmp'
```

if I remove the `command:` line it works fine but if I exec into `php` container and run the same command it gives me the same error.

Comment: `/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y php8.1-gmp` Can you try this?

Comment: I tried it `/bin/sh -c "apt-get update && apt-get install -y php8.1-gmp"` but I still get the same result

Comment: According to what source should that package exist in the default APT repository?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/z2H20TY.png

Comment: `/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y php-gmp` Please try this one

Comment: `php8.1-gmp` isn't in the bullseye apt package list. You can install `php7.4-gmp` or, as @DreamBold suggests, just use `php-gmp`.

Comment: (That `command:`, if successful, will be the only thing the container does, and then it will exit.  Do you want to `RUN` this command in a Dockerfile instead?)

Comment: I have reverted back to the image: php:7.4-fpm and then tried php7.4-gmp and php-gmp but I get this as an error messges now 'E: Package 'php7.4-gmp' has no installation candidate'